# Check if variable isset in object

Tags: php, variables, object, isset

I have object:

```
class Obj
{
    public $foo;
    public $bar;
}

$obj = new Obj();

print_R($obj);
```

Output:

```
Obj Object
(
    [foo] => 
    [bar] => 
)
```

But

```
var_dump(isset($obj->foo));
```

output **`bool(false)`**.

How to check is variable set in object?

Comment: Do you mean [`property_exists`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php)?

Comment: Haven't you done exactly what you want using `isset()`?

Comment: indeed the variable is not set.... what's the problem? read the documentation about isset, it's all explained there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because

```
$foo = null;
var_dump(isset($foo)); // false
```

Maybe you want check it with [property_exists](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php) or [ReflectionClass::hasProperty](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.hasproperty.php)

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about `null`.

Answer (score 5):

You should use a combination of both `isset` and `property_exists`:

```
if (property_exists($obj,$foo) && isset($obj->$foo)) {
   // use $obj->foo
}
```

A property may exist with nothing set into it, which won't be accessible as expected.